# Boostrap appended form-line has no focus on click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My code below appends a new input through JQuery. Page loads with only one input, and this one is working fine. When I click on it, it gets focused. The problem occurs when I append next inputs through JQuery, they seem to appear correctly, but when I click on them here's no signs of focus. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

```
<div id="keyColumn">                                                                              
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon mdi mdi-barcode mdi-18px"></span>
            <div class="form-line">
                <input id=pscKey[0] type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="1234 - 1234 - 1234 - 1234">
            </div>
        </div>                                                       
    </div>
```

Here's the JQuery part:

```
var keys = 0;
function addKey()
{
    if(++keys == 1)
    {
        $('.invisible').addClass('visible').removeClass('invisible');
    }
    $('#keyColumn').append("<div class='input-group'><span class='input-group-addon mdi mdi-barcode mdi-18px'></span><div class='form-line'><input id=pscKey[0] type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='1234 - 1234 - 1234 - 1234'></div></div>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your click event, try switching your code like this

```
$(document).on("click", ".yourSelector", function(e){
```

Instead of

```
$('.yourSelector').click(function(e){
```

Comment: can you show the code that you use to click on the appended divs? Or are you just wanting the cursor to focus inside the field immediately after being appended?

Comment: <div class="pull-right"><a href="javascript:addKey();"><i class="mdi mdi-plus"></i> Add key</a></div>

The clicking is separate element, which appends the input to specified div. The only problem is that when I click on newly appended input I don't see form-line (as on the first one)